# How can a function call affect an earlier operation?

Tags: javascript

I've ran into something in `JavaScript` that goes completely against my intuitions. I first define a function, `Shuffle(Input_array)`, that randomizes the order of an array. I then define an array, `Words`, print it to the console, and then print the result from `Shuffle(Words)`.

This is the code:

```
<script>
function Shuffle(Input_array) {
  var currentIndex = Input_array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = Input_array[currentIndex];
    Input_array[currentIndex] = Input_array[randomIndex];
    Input_array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return Input_array;
}

var Words = [["I","think"],["this","is"],["very","strange"]];
console.log(Words);
console.log(Shuffle(Words));
</script>
```

When running this script, both my calls generate the same output, namely a shuffled array. When commenting out the last `console.log` command, however, the array is printed in the order I defined it.

How is this possible? It seems like the first `console.log`output is affected in whatever happens in the second one.

It should be noted that this doesn't happen if I define my array in a 1D fashion, for example `var Words = ["This", "actually", "works"];`. I don't know if my function somehow can't handle 2D-arrays, but this shouldn't matter at all, since a later function call shouldn't be able to affect an operation predating it.

Comment: This is an artifact of the way the console shows arrays. For a multi-dimensional array it doesn't show the contents until you expand it. And you're not doing that until after you call `Shuffle()` which has changed the order.

Comment: Look at [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/dnc042/pen/KQjVXj) your code works if you output to HTML divs

Comment: You didn't comment out the second `console.log` call, you commented out the `Shuffle` call - that's the one that changes the `Words` array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javascript console contains a live copy of the array, not a snapshot of the contents when you called `console.log()`. The `Shuffle()` function modifies the array in place. If you expand the contents of the first log of the array after you call `Shuffle()`, it shows the current contents, which are in shuffled order.

The reason this doesn't happen with a 1D array is because then `console.log()` shows the contents immediately, rather than waiting for you to click on the disclosure triangle.

If you set a breakpoint between the two calls you can view the original, unshuffled contents of the array. Or you could use `console.log(JSON.stringify(Words))` to view a snapshot in text format.

Comment: Okay, I see. When placing `console.log(Words[0][0]);` in between the other two `console.log()` calls, I always get the same (correct) result, meaning at least the variable is not manipulated internally before the function call.

Answer (score 1):

It's working as intended because you're modifying the input array. In Javascript, all objects have a reference in memory, and if you modify it without creating a new instance of the object beforehand you're changing your "original" object.

And arrays are basically objects, so the same principle is applied to them.

To fix your `shuffle` method you need to create a new instance instead of directly manipulating your input array.

```js
function Shuffle(Input_array) {
  Input_array = Input_array.slice(); // creates a new instance in memory
  var currentIndex = Input_array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = Input_array[currentIndex];
    Input_array[currentIndex] = Input_array[randomIndex];
    Input_array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return Input_array;
}

var Words = [["I","think"],["this","is"],["very","strange"]];
console.log(Words);
console.log(Shuffle(Words));
console.log(Words !== Shuffle(Words));
```

Comment: @Barmar's answer is better.  The question asks why the output is affected by a subsequent operation and it has more to do with the behavior of the logger and less to do with the data being provided to `console.log`.

Comment: Yep, I'm with you. I realized it after my answer but i think it also provides some information whats going on because it's explaining some more details behind it.

Comment: Agreed, the `.slice()` adds value to the question however you're also making an assumption the OP *doesn't* want that behavior, which is inconclusive at this point.

Comment: You're right I indeed assumed that he doesn't want that behavior because i was reflecting the question from a point of view where immutable data is the key to success, that was my mistake.